# Strange text in Ag-grid pagination

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I can't post the entire code, but this is the salient part.

```
$scope.previousCandidatesGrid =
    {
        columnDefs: [ {headerName: "Candidate", field: "candidate_name"},
                      {headerName: "Skills", field: "skills"},
                      {headerName: "Start date", field: "start_date"},
                      {headerName: "End date", field: "end_date"}
                    ],
        rowData: [],  // will be added in $scope.MarkerClicked()
        pagination: true,
        paginationAutoPageSize: true,
    };
```

only the last two lines are necessary to add automating pagination according to the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pagination/).

The grid continues to display correctly - at least, its contents do. However, the pagination text looks which AG-grid generateslike this (sorry, I can't select it and copy/paste here):

[image]

clicking the "strange text" allows me to page to start/end and back forward by a page.

It's probably just a character set thing, but I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

---

[Update] as per @georgeawg's comment, I inspected those elements and got this (apologies that it is an image, I can't figure how to copy/paste it as text):

[image]

---

[Update 2] I had think that this might be either a charset problem, or CSS. I have added both `ag-grid.min.csss` and `ag-theme-balham.min.css` (because I declared the grid in HTML as `<div ag-grid="currentCandidatesGrid" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>`), but that did not help.

Comment: Inspect those elements with the Developer Console. What is the HTML and the CSS for them?

Comment: I added a screenshot (sorry, can't figure how to copy/paste. It all seems straightforward, and that HTML is injected by `ag-grid`, not me. I just added those two grid options, as per the condemnation.

Comment: The problem appears to be with the `ag-icons`. The `first`, `previous`, `next`, and `last` buttons are wrong. This is some conflict with the `ag-icons` font library.

Comment: I guess it's just a matter of knowing what I a supposed to copy from `ag-grid-master.zip`. Note that I do this manually, rather than using a package manager.

Comment: I have copied the files from github again, but still see the problem :-(

Comment: This might offer a clue ... https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-icons/

Comment: Could you show us CSS of `Next`, `Last`, `Previous`, `First` buttons? Specially `::before`. Seems like the styles of `ag-grid` are being overwritten from somewhere in  your application. So try to reference them at last when you refer them from your `html`

Comment: Would that be this? `.ag-theme-balham .ag-icon-previous:before {content: ""; }` where that unprintable character is 0xEF, 0x84, 0xA9, according to my hex editor.  I am wondering if it is a char set thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else has the same problem in future - it was the character set.

I changed

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
```

to

```
<html  lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

i.e I added the language and charset info, now I see

[image]